# How can I design a Caesar cipher encrypter and decrypter without using Non-programmable circuit components?

Tags: digital-logic, display, non-volatile-memory, encryption

[image]

My device should be able to take an input from A-Z and another input to from 0-25 and finally a Encrypt or Decrypt option. Currently I have given A a code of 0000, B 0001... so on and the output will be the result of a 4-bit adder (for encryption). I realize my circuitry skill are not profound, hence any form of support would be appreciated. Another challenge is to display each of the letters after the output is received. 
 p.s. I also realize the circuit displayed is primitive and probably incorrect.

Comment: You should probably work out and state the algorithm clearly before you try to attack it with a logic circuit

Comment: I've got a harsh suspicion: a minterm/ROM based solution will be smaller and easier to implement than the "algorithm", which you should still explicitly state and write down mathematically.

Comment: Without using *non*-programmable components? So, only programmable components? Just program one to do so...

Comment: Is this for the primitive Caesar Cipher? or for CAESAR   (
Competition   for 
Authenticated   Encryption: 
Security,  Applicability,  and  Robustness) big difference.  Also your question has a double-negative. Normally this would be programmed into a FPGA hardware which I think you are implying rather than firmware or discrete hardware IC's or software in some script language.  Start by defining your specifications.  N.B.

Answer (score -1):

Although simple in software with the mod function with a *For Loop from 1 to n* in discrete logic, it is not trivial.  We see that an Adder is useful to rotate the "Code" for an Ascii character but we can also use memory as this would not occupy much.  However try to define the basic truth table for timing each of the iterative logic in a high level function map then consider a memory lookup table rather than an adder that must check for non alphanumberic symbols gets tricky.

You may consider all the options for architecture.

Full implementation could be targetted for an FPGA.

This is a not a complete solution, but one has to start somewhere and define all the assumptions first how it works , rather than dump a primitive block diagram and say help.

- Valid ascii character table,
  character boundaries,
  rules to include only alphanumberic characters ,
  and leave other valid characters as is. such as :/;[]{}

One can choose architiecture or consider all options from Full Adder (FA) to Memory Lookup Table for each character.

One must determine if the input is valid for each string, character and reserve memory for this length limited to some max value.

Then each character is "driven" to compare if eligible for ROT-N then excute and Write the result Concatenated to the result string, then check if the string LEN down counter has reached zero.

Logic Functions must be defined at a high level then broken down into smaller rules.  Here is one way using colour mapped functions and a truth table for a high level algorithm.

[image]

Caesar Cipher is one of the weakest forms of encryption with very low entropy.

But then it was used by Julius so it has  historical interest for beginners.

Since it readily found on the web, I won't give any redundant info.

[image]

ROT-13 is a special case used in the Window registry where full path names are stored for minor reasons with obfuscation.

```
Input   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz      
Output  NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

*Jul qvq gur puvpxra pebff gur ebnq?

Gb trg gb gur bgure fvqr!*

https://learncryptography.com/classical-encryption/caesar-cipher

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question of how to _design a circuit_ to implement this algorithm.

Comment: If you're using ROT-13, I always double encrypt for extra security.

Comment: If you have something constructive to add , feel free otherwise, the question requires better specifications, which I have started. critics need not state the obvious. this was not intended to be an answer but an extended comment that does not fit in the comment section. (obviously) yet necessary to begin any design, with some history and assumptions, specs. criteria etc. Simply downvoting without constructive input is useless.  How to design a circuit ALWAYS STARTS WITH SPECS. The formula is the fundamental spec.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  Are you saying , that you use ROT-13 ? also if you double ROT-13 , you get the original. ;) I wonder if anyone has tried it in a spreadsheet with all the conditional checks.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Which is exactly what you deserve if you're using ROT-13 for security. Oh, and look behind you, I think you accidentally summoned Chthulhu.

Comment: I don't use ROT-13 encoder but Windoze does.... and I can easily decrypt the values to read it.

Comment: I wonder who has a better answer?

Comment: Apologies for the down vote. However, let me re-clarify my question. 1) The circuit is for a primitive caeser cipher. 2) I have to design it using basic logic gates (even the adders, if i use them that is). 3)  I'm terribly sorry for the delayed response. Thank you for your insight and answer.